# Has anybody used YAWS server as an HTTP Proxy?

Tags: http, proxy, erlang, yaws

I am planning to setup an YAWS webserver as a HTTP proxy server .
I am basically trying to achieve a high throughput HTTP proxy server which should be able to take webscale load.

The requirement is to be able to redirect certain URI's to our company's enterprise portal.

Has anybody used this setup in production ?
Does anybody know of any issues with the slated requirements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yaws reverse proxy stuff is pretty experimental, I wouldn't use it if that's all you need from  it.  Rather, I'd look at Varnish or even Squid.

Comment: Thanks! MrKurt , I am evaluating Varnish now , We are thinking of replacing our presnet squid basd HTTP proxy because of low throughput seen. I wanted a high perfromance HTTP proxy server and hence the rhought of YAWS came to my mind!

Answer (score 1):

YAWS is a fine application server but not more, to serve static files or for proxying it's far from ideal. We use haproxy and lighttpd in front of Yaws for better performance.